# List git branches matching multiple patterns

Tags: git, shell, version-control, branching-and-merging

I have below command to loop through list of repos and display remote branches with develop-Sprint1-* name and that are already merged to master.

for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; git branch -r --merged origin/master| awk -F/ '//develop-Sprint1-*/{print $2}'; ); done

How do I include more than one matching pattern in same command? For example, I want to above command to also list develop-Sprint2-*, develop-Sprint3-* branches.

Comment: Use regular expressions: `develop-Sprint[0123456789]-` for any single digit, `develop-Sprint[0123456789]+-` for any number of digits.